# Cannot Delete Recovered Files!

Tags: files, delete

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [General Rules for dealing with File Permissions](https://askubuntu.com/questions/35367/general-rules-for-dealing-with-file-permissions)

I recovered some files through photorec and saved them on my desktop. However, now when i try to delete them it says i do not have the permission to, and in properties it shows that root owns those files.
Any idea how do i get rid of those files?
P.S. I am new to linux so a step by step solution will be appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/33800/how-to-recover-deleted-files-and-folders?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

You could open a terminal (CTRL + ALT + T) and type `sudo nautilus` and press enter.

This way you have file access as root. BE CAREFUL NOT TO TOUCH OTHER FILES EXCEPT THE ONES YOU NEED. YOU MAY BREAK YOUR SYSTEM.

Anyway, your files will be in /home/'your username'/desktop