# Android SDK file permission

Tags: permissions, files, android, users

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [General Rules for dealing with File Permissions](https://askubuntu.com/questions/35367/general-rules-for-dealing-with-file-permissions)

I have been trying to access the file for a while now and it says that I don't have the permission to enter the file. Obviously, the user that is shown is not me.

[image: another user]

[image: permission denied]

I am currently using ubuntu 12.04LTS and I would like to know what can I do with that.
Thank you!

Comment: `sudo cd` doesn't work?

Comment: extract the android sdk as the user you downloaded it as...don't do anything with the android sdk as root.

Comment: how do I extract the SDK from it then? only with unarchiver? well then what will I do with the file that is on my computer now?

Comment: Try running `gksudo nautilus` and *carefully* deleting it, making sure to touch noting more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this in a terminal:

```
cd Downloads/
sudo chown -R YOUR_USERNAME:YOUR_USERNAME android-sdk-linux/
```

Replace `YOUR_USERNAME` with **your username**.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have the right to *read* the directory, that's why you can't see what's inside.
From your terminal, you can use the `chmod` tools like this :

```
chmod -R +r android-sdk-linux
```

This will give you the read right (+r) on all the directory inside the SDK (-R) and you will be able to enter the folder.